# Issues using api.twitter.com from Windows 2012 R2 in .NET - Twitter seem to have removed some ciphers - Anyone have any workarounds?

Tags: api, ssl, twitter, windows-server-2012-r2

Sometime yesterday, A .Net (4.7.2) app that accesses the Twitter api stopped working with an error "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" when calling System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() on Windows 2012 R2 machines.  It's fine in 2016 / 2019.

It looks like Twitter have made changes and now support only 3 ciphers:

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
```

... none of which Windows 2012R2 supports:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-cipher-suites-in-windows-8-1

Does anyone know

(a) - is there a way to update the ciphers in Windows Server 2012 R2 to support these newer ones

or

(b) - is there a way in .NET to use a different set of ciphers? (the Chrome browser, for example, continues to work in Windows 2012R2).  Or will .NET only use the machine's ciphers?

Comment: *"the Chrome browser, for example, continues to work in Windows 2012R2"* - .NET uses the native TLS stack from Windows (SChannel) and is thus limited on what the OS offers here. Chrome (and modern Edge) come with their own TLS stack BoringSSL and are thus not restricted to what the OS offers. There is probably no simple workaround here, one cannot enable ciphers which are simply not implemented.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought :(  Does anyone know of a 3rd party library etc that could be used instead of the native .NET calls, which could use the Chrome (or its own) TLS stack?  Or is this a lost cause and we just have to update all the servers?  (A nightmare as they are at customer sites all over the world).

Comment: I think if you are stuck with .NET then you are stuck with SChannel as TLS library.